# Inserting a parenthesized nickname

Tags: c, strings

Given two strings, for example

> s1 = "Valentino   Rossi" (which may contain as many spaces between the 2 words as I like)
>    s2 = "Vale"

I have to create a function that requests these two strings and that it outputs another one like this one: "Valentino (Vale) Rossi".

So for example if I have

> s1 = "Mario       Belli"
>   s2 = "Mar"

the returned string must be "Mario (Mar) Belli".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STR_LEN 32

char *makeNickname(char *s1, char *s2, char *s3);

int main() {
    char nomeCognome[] = "Corrado     Righetti"; 
    char nickname[] = "Cora";
    char nameNickname[STR_LEN];
    makeNickname(nomeCognome, nickname, nameNickname);
    printf("%s\n\n", nameNickname);
}

char *makeNickname(char *s1, char *s2, char *s3) {
    char *p = s1, *q = s2, *k = s3;
    while (*p) {
        if (*p != ' ') {
            *k++ = *p++;
        } else {
            *k++ = *p;
            *k++ = '(';
            while (*q) {
                *k++ = *q;
                q++;
            }
            *k++ = ')';
            *k++ = *p;
            while (*p == ' ') p++;
        }       
    }
    return s3;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Naming

Your variable names are polyglot, cryptic, and inconsistent.  Don't mix Italian with English — stick with English if you can.  Instead of `s1`…`s3`, pick more meaningful names.  Instead of `p`, `q`, and `k`, it would have been better to use `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` — but again, more meaningful names would be even better.

### Function signatures

In modern C, you should mark strings as `const` if you're not going to write to them.

It is customary to put `main()` at the end, so that you don't need to declare your functions.

### Approach

You aren't writing a `'\0'` terminator character to `out`, so your function won't work if the buffer is unclean.

Your solution is not robust to unexpected input, such as extra spaces at the *end* of `s1`.

Character-by-character manipulation isn't very readable.  You wouldn't want to write code like this in a larger project.  Instead, make use of the existing library functions for working with strings.  (You have already written `#include <string.h>`, so why not?)

```
char *makeNickname(const char *names, const char *nickname, char *out) {
    const char *firstSpace = strchr(names, ' ');
    const char *lastName = firstSpace + strspn(firstSpace, " ");
    sprintf(out, "%.*s (%s) %s", (int)(firstSpace - names), names, nickname, lastName);
    return out;
}
```

Note that this solution, like yours, doesn't check for buffer overflow.  It would be good practice to also pass the size of the buffer to enable such a check.

Comment: Corner case: minor bit that OP's code handles that this improved one doesn't is  when `names` contains no spaces as `firstSpace` could be `NULL`.  Suggest test for defensive programming or use `strcspn(names, " ")`.  Also: nice and complete.